# Microsoft Translator API work using console but not working within MVC

Tags: c#, controller, console-application, microsoft-translator

I have been able to get the Microsoft Translator API to work with creating a console project.  I could only find examples with using console projects.

When trying to get the Translator API working within a controller I am not having any luck.  I  am using the same code.

Do I need to add some other type of reference to get the Translator to work with in MVC?

```
public async Task<string> GetAuthenticationToken(string key)

{
  string endpoint = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken";

 using (var client = new HttpClient())
 {
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx501b7b1ce");
    var response = await client.PostAsync(endpoint, null);
    var token = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return token;
  }
}
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uEEb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you have to create the console application first and then run it as such?

Instead of running the executable from your MVC project, I would recommend calling the TranslatorAsync() function instead.

My guess would be that the process.Start() and process.Close() calls are killing the process before it has a chance to do anything.  However, without more specifics on how the function is failing, it's hard to give a better answer.

Comment: I have attached the error message.  I tried using the Microsoft Translator API within the MVC project but I could not get the token = await authTokenSource.GetAccessTokenAsync(); to work.  Plus I could not find any examples with using MVC.

Comment: Hmm. I wonder if it could have something to do with your parameters. Are the results the same if you hard code the starting parameters instead of passing them in from the command line?

Comment: Yes. The test write  File.WriteAllText("C:\\TEST\\Start.txt", productNumber.ToString()); is being executed

Answer (score 0):

I had to change

TranslateAsync(productTest, getUserName).Wait;

to

await TranslateAsync(productTest, getUserName);

It’s working now.